# Why can't I parse the following string to a JS string?

Tags: javascript, json

I obtained the following as the output of a call to `JSON.stringify`:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul id=\"BcVWDENh\">\n      <li id=\"3C\">\n        <p>Hello World</p>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

Then, I tried to call JSON parse to obtain a JS string:

```
JSON.parse(
    "\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul id=\"BcVWDENh\">\n      <li id=\"3C\">\n        <p>Hello World</p>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n\""
)
```

(I had to add double quotes around the content, and escape both)

and I get:

> Error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string (-2700)

What's happening here ?

Comment: What's the result you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Anurag Srivastava. I expect escaping from that string be removed. For example, `\"1.0\"` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output here-

```js
const myDefinedStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul id=\"BcVWDENh\">\n      <li id=\"3C\">\n        <p>Hello World</p>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n";

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDefinedStr));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, that’s perfect thank you. I have tried that. However, when I write the output of `JSON.stringify(myDefinedStr)` as a literal string, I get a Parse error.

Comment: How would you write it as a literal string?

Comment: Remove the double quotes and add single quotes around the content & add double all backslashes instead of single backslashes like this-

'"<?xml version=\\"1.0\\" encoding=\\"UTF-8\\"?>\\n<html>\\n  <head>\\n    <meta charset=\\"utf-8\\"/>\\n  </head>\\n  <body>\\n    <ul id=\\"BcVWDENh\\">\\n      <li id=\\"3C\\">\\n        <p>Hello World</p>\\n      </li>\\n    </ul>\\n  </body>\\n</html>\\n"'

Comment: `\"` in a JavaScript string literal inserts a `"` character. A literal `"` in a JSON string will terminate that string.

Answer (score 1):

What you call the "output of a call to `JSON.stringify`" is actually a *printout* of the output. When you want to feed this string into `JSON.parse`, you must double all backslashes:

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").textContent = JSON.parse('"<?xml version=\\"1.0\\" encoding=\\"UTF-8\\"?>\\n<html>\\n  <head>\\n    <meta charset=\\"utf-8\\"/>\\n  </head>\\n  <body>\\n    <ul id=\\"BcVWDENh\\">\\n      <li id=\\"3C\\">\\n        <p>Hello World</p>\\n      </li>\\n    </ul>\\n  </body>\\n</html>\\n"');
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```